# Nautilus using ~4 CPU-seconds to open an empty directory

Tags: nautilus, performance, 19.10

Aka. Nautilus is insanely slow, at least two orders of magnitude slower than other file managers. I'm using a laptop with a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10, and opening *any* directory, even empty ones right in my home directory, takes several seconds and uses 100% CPU the entire time.

What I've tried so far:

1. Setting "Show thumbnails" to "Never".
2. Setting "Count number of files in folders" to "Never".
3. `rm -rf ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/` and restarting Nautilus.
4. `systemctl --user unmask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service` and rebooting.

The machine only has a single permanent storage drive, an SSD.

Something which might be related is that it adds a bunch of "Duplicate child name in GtkStack: [directory name]" warning entries in the systemd journal every time I change directory. Other than that the only output from Nautilus is this, the first line of output after starting it:

> Nautilus-Share-Message: 08:56:35.119: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

To be absolutely clear, this is definitely a Nautilus or Ubuntu specific issue, since I've not seen anything like it in the last five or so years running several other GUI file managers on Arch Linux and NixOS with the same hardware.

Comment: For me, Nautilus is very snappy. It might be an issue with Tracker, such as corruption of the database. Disable and reset: `systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service ; tracker reset --hard` and reboot. Test. Reverse: `systemctl --user unmask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`. Reboot. Tracker now will recreate the database.

Comment: No go @vanadium :/

Comment: It was a possibility that this way is ruled out. You could run nautilus from the terminal and then post some of the output while you do a few of these actions that go slowly in your message. It may or may not provide a clue.

Comment: @vanadium I've included the output; it looks like the slowness could be related to traversing the entire `GtkStack`, whatever that is, a bunch of times for every directory navigation.